# Is there anyway to exit from a command in Terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, macos-mojave

When I type

> python

In the command line, for example, is there any way​ to exit out without closing the terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really depends on the ran command.
In python, you call a function:

```
exit();
```

Terminal actions are nothing but a bash script or a program itself, in some cases, interruptions like:

> Ctrl + 'Z' - SIGSTOP 
>  Ctrl + 'C' - SIGINT 
>  Ctrl + '\' - SIGQUIT 
>  Ctrl + 'D' - SIGHUP

Will work just fine, however due to implementations or buffer reading, it won't always work, but usually it's something among those lines like 'quit()', 'exit()' or even '\q' on Postgres.

The best course of actions is always reading the specific tool documentation.

Comment: thanks for your effort. Please note, Ctrl Z: Used to suspend foreground processes, hence this will not exit from current session of python. However Ctrl D: Used to terminate input or exit the terminal or shell

Comment: @ManojRana Added clarification regarding that, thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 0):

Use exit() or Ctrl-D (i.e. EOF) to exit